# Update ImageView in QML

Tags: qml, qqmlapplicationengine

I am processing an image using opencv during runtime and want to display the updated version of this image in QML using imageView, i currently am creating a new image file at runtime and reassigning its path to the imageView in QML, is there any better method for this?

Comment: Maybe you can use a similar approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability/27429586#27429586

Comment: What's an imageView?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it is something that views an image. However, his problem is a simple as the design flaw with Qt properties where internal changes do not emit a changed() signal, only a reassignment. The solution is only reassign a thin wrapper still pointing to the internally changed object, this fakes a reassignment without doing the costly data copy.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I do this by connecting a changed signal emitted from the c++ code and connect it to a receiver that forces a reload on the qml side :

```
// MyImage.qml
Image {
    cache: false
    function reload() {
        var tmpSource = source;
        source = "";
        source = tmpSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u explain what you mean by the reciever?