# QML ListView data retreival from mysql database

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qml

I my test database, I have table named **users**, which represents loggable users. Now, I've succesfully connected to database through Qt/C++, exposed class to QML (also without problems), setup QML `ListView` to show this users with custom model and delegate (file `main.qml`) and when I run my app, five items are shown in `ListView`. Now, `ListView's` delegate is composed from **Image** and **Text** sections (**Image section** for loggable user image, which resides as **BLOB** in mysql database and **Text section** for user name, which also resides as **VARCHAR** in mysql database - both fields are in same table named **users**):

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Item
{
    id: uePeopleItemDelegate

    property Image uePersonImage
    property string uePersonName

    width: 256
    height: 256
    antialiasing: true

    clip: true

    Rectangle
    {
        id: ueRectangleMain
        color: "#000000"

        radius: 16
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        border.color: "#ffffff"
        border.width: 4
        clip: true
        //opacity: 0.7

        Grid
        {
            antialiasing: true
            anchors.rightMargin: 12
            anchors.leftMargin: 12
            anchors.bottomMargin: 12
            anchors.topMargin: 12
            anchors.fill: parent
            spacing: 4
            rows: 2
            columns: 1
        }

        Row
        {
            id: ueRowImage
            anchors.rightMargin: 12
            anchors.leftMargin: 12
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.bottomMargin: 48
            anchors.topMargin: 12
        }

        Image
        {
            id: uePersonleImage
            x: 12
            y: 12
            width: 232
            height: 196
            antialiasing: true
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: ""
        }

        Column
        {
            id: ueColumnPeopleInfo
            x: 12
            y: 214
            width: 232
            height: 30
            spacing: 0
        }

        Text
        {
            id: ueTextPersonName
            x: 12
            y: 214
            width: 232
            height: 30
            color: "#ffffff"
            text: uePersonName
            font.bold: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            font.pixelSize: 16
        }
    }
}
```

And here is screenshot of delegates:
[image: ListView delegates]

If I delete/add user in database, the number of delegates changes according to number of table user records, which works perfect. But now I have two problems: In `main.qml`, I instantiate this `ListView`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtTest 1.1

import "gui/delegates"

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: ueWindowMain

    title: qsTr("TestApp")

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth

    visible: true

    opacity: 1.0

    contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation

    color: "black"

    ListView
    {
        id: uePeopleListView
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.ApplyRange
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottom: parent.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: -128
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
        antialiasing: true
        spacing: 16
        delegate: UePeopleItemDelegate
        {
            id: uePersonDelegate

            uePersonImage: ""   // Q1: How do I retreive image (user image) from database?
            uePersonName: ""    // Q2: How do I retreive text (user name) from database?
        }
        model: uePeopleModel
    }
}
```

How do I retreive data (image and text) to show it in delegate in lines **49** and **50**? Here are also header and implementation of my model class:

```
#ifndef UEPEOPLEMODEL_H
#define UEPEOPLEMODEL_H

#include <QImage>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QHash>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQueryModel>
#include <QtSql/QSqlRecord>
#include <QModelIndex>

#include "../settings/uedefaults.h"

class UePeopleModel : public QSqlQueryModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> m_ueRoleNames;

    void ueGenerateRoleNames();

public:
    UePeopleModel(QObject *parent=0);
    ~UePeopleModel();

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index,
                  int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void ueRefresh();
    inline QHash<int, QByteArray> ueRoleNames() const
        { return this->m_ueRoleNames; }
};

#endif // UEPEOPLEMODEL_H
```

and implementation:

```
#include "uepeoplemodel.h"

UePeopleModel::UePeopleModel(QObject* parent)
    : QSqlQueryModel(parent)
{
    QSqlDatabase db;

    if(!QSqlDatabase::connectionNames().contains(UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionNames::DATABASE_CONNECTION_NAME_PEOPLE,
                                                 Qt::CaseInsensitive))
    {
            db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(UePosDatabase::DATABASE_DRIVER,
                                         UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionNames::DATABASE_CONNECTION_NAME_PEOPLE);
    }   // if

    db.setHostName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbHostname()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_HOSTNAME);
    db.setDatabaseName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbName()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_NAME);
    db.setUserName(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbUser()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_USERNAME);
    db.setPassword(/*this->uePosSettings()->ueDbPassword()*/UePosDatabase::UeDatabaseConnectionParameters::DATABASE_PASSWORD);

    if(db.open())
    {
        this->setQuery(UePosDatabase::UeSqlQueries::UeTablePeople::SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PEOPLE,
                       db);
        this->ueGenerateRoleNames();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
    }
}   // default constructor

UePeopleModel::~UePeopleModel()
{
}   // default destructor

QVariant UePeopleModel::data(const QModelIndex &index,
                             int role) const
{
    QVariant value;

    if(role<Qt::UserRole)
    {
        value=QSqlQueryModel::data(index,
                                   role);
    }
    else
    {
        int iColumnIndex=role-Qt::UserRole-1;
        QModelIndex modelIndex=this->index(index.row(),
                                           iColumnIndex);

        value=QSqlQueryModel::data(modelIndex,
                                   Qt::DisplayRole);
    }   // if

    return value;

//    QVariant value=QSqlQueryModel::data(index,
//                                        role);

//    if(value.isValid()&&role==Qt::DisplayRole)
//    {
//        switch(index.column())
//        {
//            case UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_ID:
//                return value.toInt();

//            case UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_NAME:
//                return value.toString();

//            case UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_APPPASSWORD:
//                return value.toString();

//            case UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_CARD:
//                return value.toString();

//            case UePosDatabase::UeTableIndexes::UeTablePeople::INDEX_IMAGE:
//            {
//                QImage image;

//                image.loadFromData(value.toByteArray());

//                return image;
//            }   // case

//            default:
//                return value;
//        }   // switch
//    }   // if

//    return QVariant();
}   // data

void UePeopleModel::ueRefresh()
{
    this->setQuery(UePosDatabase::UeSqlQueries::UeTablePeople::SQL_QUERY_GET_ALL_PEOPLE);
}   // ueRefresh

void UePeopleModel::ueGenerateRoleNames()
{
    this->ueRoleNames().clear();
    for(int iIndex=0; iIndex<this->record().count(); iIndex++)
    {
        this->ueRoleNames().insert(Qt::UserRole+1+iIndex,
                                   this->record().fieldName(iIndex).toUtf8());
    }   // for
}   // ueGenerateRoleNames
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default QML image provider can only work with URLs or file paths. If you want to load a QML image from a C++ image class, such as `QPixmap` or `QImage` you will have to go about and implement your own image provider. I've described [one possible implementation strategy here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability/27429586#27429586):

After that it is fairly straightforward, the `data()` method won't be returning an image wrapped in a `QVariant`, just a custom image URL targeted at the custom image provider, and that's what you are going to use in the QML delegate. Naturally, inside the database, you will still have a blob, and you will still use the `fromData()` method to construct the image, however the image provider will be used to associate the custom image source string to the actual image. Naturally, you must find a way to control the lifetime of the actual image so you don't get memory leaks. My suggestion is to implement something like the `Pixmap` item from the answer listed above, and make it a part of your delegate - this way the image will be deleted when no longer needed. You will however also need to implement `setData()` for the `Pixmap` and pass the `QPixmap` pointer in text form and store it in `pix`.

It might be easier and wiser to NOT store the image in the database, but as a regular file, and just store the relative path to it in the database, it will save you some trouble. As for the question "how to retrieve data" - I'd say go there and actually [read the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html#details)...

Comment: wil follow your path and I agree NOT to store image in a datababse, but at this point, the system is as is and NOT developed by me, I am just working on eye candy client (Qt/QML) that will fit on android devices.