# Display decoration in ListView delegate

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a C++ model that is used in QML. It's working fine, but I have problems showing decoration. How can I display icons in QML? I have searched the documentation and the web, no success. `Image` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- provide the icon as a string with a path to the icon file and use an `Image` element in QML to load the icon from the path string.
- provide the icon as a `QImage` and [use a custom image provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability/27429586#27429586) to use the `QImage` as a source for a QML `Image`.

The second approach is overkill in your case, but still, image interop between C++ and QML is possible if you need it in future.