# How to load images (jpg) in QML generated at runtime

Tags: image, qt, load, runtime, qml

my question is quite simple.
I have a Qt application with a Gui developed with QML.
My back-end side generates and saves jpg images in a folder called /images . 
I am able to send from C++ to QML the strings holding the name of the images that I want to show. Sadly my QML Image object doesn't display anything.

It seems that if an image can be displayed only if it has been previously declared in the qml.qrc file.
Sadly, again, qrc files do not support wildcards yet!
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-1400

Is there a workaround?
The name of the images are not fixed, they are generated with certain runtime values i.e. timestamp.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps you need [QQuickImageProvider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html)

Comment: Nah, he just needs to load from disk rather than rqc

Comment: I might need QQuickImageProvider, but it's a pain in the ass since in my backend I handle multiple images (generated at runtime) for each model exposed to QML.  

Using QQuickImageProvider should be quicker in any case.. rather than storing and loading images. I will give it a shot tomorrow. thx

Comment: If you decide to go the image provider way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability

Comment: ok Thank you!  I'll try.. or I'll move to QWidgets >(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it will search the image source in the qrc file. To make it go to the actual file system, prepend a `file:///` to the path.

Comment: yeah, it worked perfectly coupled with `cache:false`. 
I'll try the performance of this implementation before switching to something else. Thx

Comment: Since the files names come from C++, just use `QUrl::fromLocalFile()` and hand the resulting URL to QML