# Qt QML: UI with dynamic number of images provided by c++ code

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am designing an application that, in essence, gets a number of images (which change - think of several videos consisting of many images each, displayed in sequence) which I want to display in a grid pattern. This pattern should be extensible, I want to be able to control row and column count dynamically.

A C++ core application provides these images at varying speeds. It needs to know where to send them.

My team and I have already created a prototype which fits some of those requirements: we are able to instance a C++ based object, derived from `QQuickPaintedItem`, which paints its image in the overwritten `paint(QPainter *painter)` method. In QML, several of these are then instanced and they display their images as I would expect. However, the image content is hard-coded and as these objects are instanced in QML, I'm unsure as to how I would control their contents from my core application in C++. Furthermore, the way we dynamically arrange them is an extremely dirty hack derived from trial and error and works only marginally close to how it is intended: the instances are simply destroyed and recreated whenever the "add one more" button is pressed.

My question is probably a matter of design principle. Even after examining a few examples and further research I am unsure what's the best way to combine the core application and the QML code to achieve what I want.

What is the right approach here? I suspect Models and Views might be the way to go, as I believe I could be able to add the Player components to the model via C++ and therefore have access to them there, while QML would ... somehow ... handle the displaying and arranging.

I'm sorry for the rather vague question, I hope you can help me with a few pointers into the right direction, as to which mechanics I could use to combine QML and C++ for my purposes.

Comment: Have you tried to supply your images to an `ImageProvider`? Then you might add the identifier to a `ListModel`, and display the images using a `Image` as `delegate` within a `GridView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QPaintedItem` is unnecessary and will likely constitute performance overhead.

As already mentioned, what you really need to do is implement a `QQuickImageProvider` which can allow you to [do C++ / QML image interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability).

Then regardless of whether you need rows, columns or grids, those are all driven by models, you don't necessarily have to implement a C++ mode, QML's `ListModel` will suffice, as all you really need is a list model of strings, representing the image sources for the custom image provider.

Every time you have a new image coming from C++, you can emit a signal from the C++ side with the image source string, to which you connect a handler on the QML side to add a list item to the model. Expose the emitting object to QML as a context property. As soon as a signal is emitted, the new image source is added to the model and automatically shown in the view. That's pretty much it.

Comment: That sounds really good, I already thought that painting it myself might be bad for performance, and performance is quite critical for this application. One thing troubles me a little: you say "strings, representing the image sources" - likely, I don't have the images as files or resources, but purely in the RAM, likely as a QImage. I'll look into the ImageProvider and everything you've mentioned though.

Comment: @JayEff - if you look at the provider in the answer I have linked, its source is not an image url, but a string representing a pointer in memory. Image providers work with source strings, there is no way around that, but the string can be anything. If you need uniformity across application runs, instead of  using a pointer use a `QSet` or `QMap` to resolve identifiers to image pointers.

Comment: Thanks for this, this seems to be exactly what I need. One last question regarding this method (from your link): I see that QString::number is used to convert the pixmap to a QString. How fast is this conversion, and also, how ... "performance efficient" (if that makes sense) is the entire mechanism? I don't think I need to coax every last bit of performance out of my code by applying crazy hacks, I'm just wondering if this is capable of, let's say, at least 4 video streams at 20 ish fps at, say, 720p on a mid to high tier PC. (I doubt you can answer that directly, just a rough guess...?)

Comment: It should be fast enough, definitely better than alternative method such as using a hash or a map for lookup. Use a `QElapsedTimer` to measure it if you want. There is one possibility to make it faster - instead of parsing integers you can create a raw base64 string directly from the pointer bits, but I doubt it will be worth the extra work.

Comment: Sorry, I feel I'm misunderstanding something. As I understand your link, the Pixmap class is instanced in QML, and the pixmap class handles the loading of an image. But my initial problem was, that I wasn't able to control the content of my QML objects from C++, and this doesn't seem to allow me to do that either... Perhaps your idea was that I completely rewrite the Pixmap::data() and PixmapProvider::requestPixmap methods so that I can provide my images in an entirely different way? I set the data() as a property in QML to an identifier which is interpreted in the ImageProvider?

Comment: SORRY! Problem solved, it's of course :/zahnrad, since this is not an URL but a file path (if I understand it right - either way, this works) - This doesn't mean my previous problem was solved, I'm still not sure how to control the content from C++ properly. Just now I used a Q_INVOCABLE to cause the loading via QML. Also, maybe more importantly, with the method I described above, I can't cause an update from c++, so it really doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JayEff - you only need the provider, not the `Pixmap` component - that's for QML loading of images. It uses 64bit integer for the pointer conversion, so it should work regardless if it is 32 or 64 bit build. The `Pixmap` provides a source for the image provider, in your case that will come from C++.

Comment: (The last comment referred to a comment I deleted. I planned to edit the last comment to reflect that but I ran into the "can't edit after 5 minutes" error. I feel like I'm using stackoverflow wrong. Sorry... ) Alright, thank you, I understand that part now, I will be able to implement this - one last thing, as mentioned above: The ImageProvider won't cause an update when I change the content, will it? How do I tell QML to check for a new image, perhaps a kind of timer in QML?

Comment: @JayEff - as mentioned in the linked answer, you can force the updating only if you change the source string, the API is not really designed to handle partial changes, only the entire image. When an image updates, just remove it from the model and then insert it back again, that will reload it. Reloading is unavoidable, since you have to copy from RAM to video RAM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132424/discussion-between-jayeff-and-ddriver).