# Shader to render QR code

Tags: qt, shader, opengl-es-2.0, qr-code, qtquick2

What is the best (in sense of performance and memory consumption) way to represent QR code graphically in *Qt Quick* application?

I think QR code bitmap can be represented graphically as square matrix of black and white cells using some shader. It would be performance-optimal solution.

Currently I can only create a *GridView* with a bunch of *Rectangle*s. It is considered as a waste of memory to store and CPU/GPU time to render.

How may the shader looks like?

Say, given `QBitArray` of `n*n` size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shader itself would be trivial, basically you divide the fragment position x and y by the qr code size and floor that to get row and column, and then find the 1d index by adding the two, then lookup the qt data array at that index, if it contains a 0, the fragment color is white, if it contains 1, the color is black.

However, QML shaders currently don't provide facilities to pass regular 1d arrays.

You would have to convert the array to a bitmap image, and pass it to the array, which means you will also have to implement an image provider in order to get `QImage` to work with QML, because amazingly, it still doesn't by default.

I wouldn't bother about performance too much, that's premature optimization, which is bad in 99% of the cases. Even a trivial, 100% QML solution is sufficiently fast:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: main
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  color: "darkgray"

  property var qrdata: []

  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
      qrdata = []
      for (var i = 0; i < (100 * 100); ++i) qrdata.push(Math.round(Math.random()))
      code.requestPaint()
    }
  }

  Canvas {
    id: code
    width: 300
    height: 300
    onPaint: {
      console.time("p")
      var c = getContext("2d")
      c.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(1, 1, 1, 1);
      c.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)
      c.fillStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      var l = qrdata.length
      var step = Math.sqrt(l)
      var size = width / step
      for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
        if (qrdata[i]) {
          var rw = Math.floor(i / step), cl = i % step
          c.fillRect(cl * size, rw * size, size, size)
        }
      }
      console.timeEnd("p")
    }
  }
}
```

On my system, drawing a 100 x 100 qr code takes about 2 milliseconds. IMO that's sufficiently good and it is not really worth it to invest time into making are more complex low level solution.

However, what I would personally do is implement an [image provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27429371/qml-and-c-image-interoperability), convert the qr code data into an image, then scale that image as large as I want with `smooth: false` which will avoid blurring and preserve a crisp result. That is by far the most direct, efficient and straightforward solution.

Comment: Is it possible to generate non-raster image? Say, SVG xml?

Comment: @Orient - there is no point, because SVG still gets rasterized to render at a particular size. A SVG QR code will take up more space than a bitmap. If you disable smooth, the bitmap will scale up perfectly and indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got just one QR code in the application then save your time and do a GridView.

Other options are:

- C++ custom `QQuickItem`: generate and load a texture (Qt SceneGraph API)
- C++ custom `QQuickFramebufferObject`: generate and load a texture (mostly pure OpenGL API)
- C++ custom `QQuickPaintedItem`(QPainter 2D API)
- QML-JS Canvas/Context2D (HTML 2D API)
- QML-JS Canvas3D/Context3D: generate and load a texture (WebGL API) - like all other C++ options, but in JS version of OpenGL
- C++ custom `QQuickImageProvider`: generate and load a texture (ImageProvider and OpenGL API) while passing the whole QR data as an image name to your custom `QQuickImageProvider` (maybe a bit too clever)

Using vertex-buffers/uniform-buffers instead of textures may work, but it needs an unusual shader code. QR fits more as a texture, I think.

Comment: On the contrary, the shader will actually be an extremely usual and trivial one.